# Split one column csv data into multiple columns by number of rows

Tags: php, python, bash, python-2.7

I'm new on this site, hope I'm doing my question properly and on the right side, if not, please any tip will be appreciated.

Just need some guidance with a problem.

I've a csv file like this:

```
| Column1|
----------
abc
def
ghi
12,34
32,67
jkl
mno
pqr
28,34
98,67
```

(really bad file)

And I want to transform into this kind of csv:

```
Something1 | Something2 | Something3 | Something4 | Something5
---------------------------------------------------------------
   abc     |    def     |     ghi    |    12,34   |    32,67
   jkl     |    mno     |     pqr    |    28,34   |    98,67
```

There're a total of 15 types of data on 15 consecutive rows on variable number of repeat times and I need to split'em into 15 columns in a new csv file.

My first tought was making a bash script with a function to count lines and split the data by the number of line into a new csv file but I realized the fact maybe it's better to do it using another way or use some pythonic way (with pandas and numpy ) or a PhP webservice (`fopen` and exploding data or something like that) because this is not going to be the last time I get that kind of trash csv file...

But I need some guidance to start with.

Some help will be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using spacing and `|` chars to separate the data? Would `abd;def;ghi;12,34;32,67` work as well?

Comment: Well it was a try to make a graphical example to make the things easy to understand but seems i got the opposite effect >.< , ofc the result should be as u say. Should I edit the post ?

Comment: Don't worry, just asking for clarification

Comment: I answered just using the standard Python library, didn't check it as I don't have the files but it should work. Post in answer's comments if you find a bug.

Comment: Sry about my late response (fixing some server issues) Thank you so much, it worked so nice and it was a clean code to understand ! Also i'm so impressed how fast the people answer the questions. Thank you so much to everybody. Should i close the question somewhere? or just leave it ?

Comment: Marking an answer as the accepted one is just enough. You can also upvote answers, but that is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution just uses the standard library:

```
from csv import writer

COLUMNS = 15

with open("input_file.csv", "r") as input:
    with open("output_file.csv", "w") as f:
        output = writer(f, delimiter=";")
        output.writerow(["Col {}".format(i+1) for i in xrange(COLUMNS)])
        buffer = []
        for row in input:
            buffer.append(row)
            if len(buffer) == COLUMNS:
                output.writerow(buffer)
                del buffer[:]
        // You may want to check if there is something inside buffer at the end, for example if it has 23 rows buffer here will contain 8 elements and you may want to append them with: output.writerow(buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
numCol = 15

columns = [["col" + i] for i in xrange(numCol)]

with open("...") as f:
    for (i, line) in enumerate(f[1:]):
        columns[i % numCol].append(line.rstrip())

csv = zip(*columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is generally a nice way to deal with csv data. As an example of how to convert into a pandas DataFrame:

```python
f = open("yourfile", "r").readlines()  # Your file

# Split into groups
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
import pandas as pd

cols = itertools.cycle(range(5))  # Use appropriate names for columns here

# Add your data to your column names in a cycle
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in f[2:]:
    d[next(cols)].append(i)

print pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)



>>>      0    1    2      3      4
0  abc  def  ghi  12,34  32,67
1  jkl  mno  pqr  28,34  98,67
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input and output file consist only of the data shown in your question:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    izip = zip

def grouper(n, iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,...s3n-1), ..."
    return izip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

with open('trash.csv', 'r') as infile, open('pretty.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    next(infile)  # skip input header
    outfile.write('Something1|Something2|Something3|Something4|Something5\n') # new header
    for group in grouper(5, (line.strip() for line in infile)):
        #print('|'.join(group))
        outfile.write('|'.join(group)+'\n')
```